# Importing xslt stylesheet with relative path

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XSLT file that uses xsl:import element to load some common templates.
I would like to use it in ?xml-stylesheet declaration to convert some XML into HTML (make it readable for user).

The problem is that the the server used for hosting xsl file will depend on the concrete deployment and cannot be hardcoded upfront (so no absolute path for me).
I would gladly use relative path but when I try to change import href to relative like "/other.xsl" or "other.xsl" the browser fails to import the common stylesheet.

Just to be a bit more concrete - the url for main xsl file looks like this:

```
https://test.com/some/path/servlet.jsp/service/stles/main.xsl
```

And the browser tries to load imported xsl from following addres:

```
https://test.com/other.xsl
```

and the other.xsl stylesheet resides here:

```
https://test.com/some/path/servlet.jsp/service/stles/other.xsl
```

Why relative address does not work in this case?
And is there a way to force it to work (other than rewriting the xsl file content on the server to change import url).

Comment: Is that a specific browser? What kind of failure does the network console show?

Comment: I tested this in chrome. The error is simple - that https://test.com/other.xsl does not exist (and it does not because the real url is the longer one mentioned in question)

Comment: Given the main URL `https://test.com/some/path/servlet.jsp/service/stles/main.xsl` and the one to be imported as `https://test.com/some/path/servlet.jsp/service/stles/other.xsl` it appears that `xsl:import href="other.xsl"` should work while `xsl:import href="/other.xsl"` obviously doesn't make sense. Which error do you get for `xsl:import href="other.xsl"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have left out some important parts that changes this question a little bit.
I experimented with few implementations and I think I mixed the standard xml-stylesheet with js one.

The final version was using xslt transformation through js XSLTProcessor.
The stylesheet was loaded with fetch -> xml dom object for xsl -> importStyleSheet(xslDomObj). And the problem was that the xsl contains import element which was computing bad relative path (it may be due to the fact that xsl is loaded through dom object and not url).

I added simple replacement for src of import that changed relative path to absolute path and this solved my problem (at least the immediate one - because as far as I can see this does not address problems with imports that are parts of the imported xsl).